# How can i serve a file through a php script and make it behave exactly the same as a direct link to the file?

Tags: php, http-headers, mp4, jwplayer

I use a php script to check if a user is logged in before serving images or videos.  The actual files are stored in a folder that is not able to be accessed directly.  If the authentication is successful, the php script will relay/output the file.  My goal is to have the file served through the php script behave as closely as possible as a direct link to the actual file.

So, here's the deal. Images work fine.  Videos (mp4) work with a few caveats.  I'm not able to pseudo stream using the h264.code-shop.com streaming module and the video only successfully plays through once on an iphone.  Once the video reaches the end i cannot replay the video without refreshing the page and i receive a "video could not be loaded" error (JW player). If i bypass the php script and directly link to the video file, everything works properly. Therefore it is apparent there is something different between the output generated from my php script and the output you would normally get from directly accessing the file. So, to all you experts out there, what could i possibly be missing?  The correct http headers?  What can i do to make my script output a file the exact same way the file would be sent if accessed directly?

Here's the script i'm using:

```
<?php

if (!isset($_GET['f'])){die(header('location:../login.php'));}
if (!isset($_GET['onlyHappensFromHTACCESS'])) {
$_GET['f'] = "../protectedFolder/".$_GET['f'];
$file = realpath($_GET['f']);
$type = getFileType($file);
if (acceptableType($type))
 {
 if (goodTiming())
  {
  //this function used to allow navigation away from the page while video has not completely loaded
  session_write_close();

  $fs = stat($file);

  header("Content-Type: $type");
  header("Etag: ".sprintf('"%x-%x-%s"', $fs['ino'], $fs['size'],base_convert(str_pad($fs['mtime'],16,"0"),10,16)));

  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
   { // do it for any device that supports byte-ranges not only iPhone
   rangeDownload($file);
   }
  else
   {
   $size   = filesize($file); // File size

   header("Content-Length: $size");
   header("Last-Modified: " .gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s")." GMT");
   header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
   header("Pragma: no-cache");
   header("Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100");
   header("Connection: Keep-Alive");

   $fh = fopen($file, "rb");

   while ( ($buf=fread( $fh, 1024 * 8 )) != '' )
    {
    set_time_limit(0); // Reset time limit for big files
    echo $buf;
    flush();
    }

   fclose($fh);
   }
  }
 die();
 }
header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
die(header('location:../login.php'));
}

function getFileType($file) {
if (function_exists("finfo_open")) {
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
if ($file==false){$file=realpath("../authorization_failure.html");}
$type = finfo_file($finfo, $file);
finfo_close($finfo);
return $type;
}
else {
$types = array(
  'jpg' => 'image/jpeg', 'jpeg' => 'image/jpeg', 'pjpeg' => 'image/jpeg', 'png' => 'image/png',
  'gif' => 'image/gif', 'bmp' => 'image/bmp', 'flv' => 'video/x-flv', 'mp4' => 'video/mp4'
);
$ext = substr($file, strrpos($file, '.') + 1);
if (key_exists($ext, $types)) return $types[$ext];
return "unknown";
}
}


function acceptableType($type) {
$array = array("image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png", "image/png", "video/x-flv", "video/mp4");
if (in_array($type, $array))
    return true;
return false;
}


function goodTiming() {
$n = time();
session_start();
if ($n - $_SESSION['lastcheck'] > 15 )
    return false;
return true;
}

function rangeDownload($file) {

$fp = @fopen($file, 'rb');

$size   = filesize($file); // File size
$length = $size;           // Content length
$start  = 0;               // Start byte
$end    = $size - 1;       // End byte
// Now that we've gotten so far without errors we send the accept range header
/* At the moment we only support single ranges.
 * Multiple ranges requires some more work to ensure it works correctly
 * and comply with the spesifications: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.2
 *
 * Multirange support annouces itself with:
 * header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
 *
 * Multirange content must be sent with multipart/byteranges mediatype,
 * (mediatype = mimetype)
 * as well as a boundry header to indicate the various chunks of data.
 */
header("Accept-Ranges: 0-$length");
// header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
// multipart/byteranges
// http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.2
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {

    $c_start = $start;
    $c_end   = $end;
    // Extract the range string
    list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
    // Make sure the client hasn't sent us a multibyte range
    if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {

        // (?) Shoud this be issued here, or should the first
        // range be used? Or should the header be ignored and
        // we output the whole content?
        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
        // (?) Echo some info to the client?
        exit;
    }
    // If the range starts with an '-' we start from the beginning
    // If not, we forward the file pointer
    // And make sure to get the end byte if spesified
    if ($range== '-') {

        // The n-number of the last bytes is requested
        $c_start = $size - substr($range, 1);
    }
    else {

        $range  = explode('-', $range);
        $c_start = $range[0];
        $c_end   = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] : $size;
    }
    /* Check the range and make sure it's treated according to the specs.
     * http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html
     */
    // End bytes cannot be larger than $end.
    $c_end = ($c_end > $end) ? $end : $c_end;
    // Validate the requested range and return an error if it's not correct.
    if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $size - 1 || $c_end >= $size) {

        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
        // (?) Echo some info to the client?
        exit;
    }
    $start  = $c_start;
    $end    = $c_end;
    $length = $end - $start + 1; // Calculate new content length
    fseek($fp, $start);
    header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
}
// Notify the client the byte range we'll be outputting
header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
header("Content-Length: $length");

// Start buffered download
$buffer = 1024 * 8;
while(!feof($fp) && ($p = ftell($fp)) <= $end) {

    if ($p + $buffer > $end) {

        // In case we're only outputtin a chunk, make sure we don't
        // read past the length
        $buffer = $end - $p + 1;
    }
    set_time_limit(0); // Reset time limit for big files
    echo fread($fp, $buffer);
    flush(); // Free up memory. Otherwise large files will trigger PHP's memory limit.
}

fclose($fp);

}


header('location:../login.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I use mod_xsendfile for this
https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/

Let Apache deal with serving the file, rather than trying to replicate it all in PHP :)

Comment: of course I dont actully know you using Apache, but the reference to htaccess suggests might be...

Comment: Xsendfile definitely simplifies my code and probably increases my site's efficiency as well.  However, the same two problems i had with my original script are still present when using xsendfile.  Namely, pseudo-streaming doesn't work and idevices only play the video through once before throwing an error.  Have you experienced any of those problems with your setup?  Any solutions to these issues? Definitely a helpful suggestion though and spot on about me using apache, so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its easy to do. No need to set those headers manually. Let the server do it automatically.

Heres a working script which I wrote for a video streaming proxy -

```
ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');

set_time_limit(3600);

ob_start();

**// do any user checks here - authentication / ip restriction / max downloads / whatever**

**// if check fails, return back error message**

**// if check succeeds, proceed with code below**

if( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']) )

$opts['http']['header']="Range: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'];

$opts['http']['method']= "HEAD";

$conh=stream_context_create($opts);

$opts['http']['method']= "GET";

$cong= stream_context_create($opts);

$out[]= file_get_contents($real_file_location_path_or_url,false,$conh);

$out[]= $http_response_header;

ob_end_clean();

array_map("header",$http_response_header);

readfile($real_file_location_path_or_url,false,$cong);
```